How to avoid stack smashing detected in C? What is wrong with the code below?
I'm making a program which automates Luhn's algorithm; it takes every other number of a credit card starting with the first one, multiplies them by two, and adds the multiplied the added numbers together. I've not finished, but have encountered a problem called "stack smashing detected". Can anybody offer help or advice?
Here is the code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    long card;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the card number: ");
        scanf("%li", &card);
    }
    while (card < 1000000000000000);

    int y = 10;
    int z = 15;
    int x = 1;
    int arr[8];

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        double result = pow(y,z); 

        double a = (card / result); 
        long roundedA = floor(a);

        double b = roundedA /10;
        long roundedB = floor(b);
        long c = roundedB * 10;
        int d = roundedA - c;
        z = z-2;

        arr[x] = d;
        x++;
    }

    int newarr[8];
    int arraynumber;
    for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        arraynumber = 2 * arr[j];
        newarr[j] = arraynumber;
    }  

    int sum = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
    {
        sum = sum + newarr[k];
    }

    if (sum % 10 == 0)
    {
        printf("This checks out, boss.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Security will escort you out of the building big man.");
    }
}

I have no idea what this means, so I don't know what to try.

arr[x] = d; when x is 8 causes your issue! The eight valid elements of arr are: arr[0], arr[1], ..., and arr[7].

Does this answer your question? Stack smashing detected

int x = 1; should probably be int x = 0;

Do you realise that long may not be a large enough type? Use strings to input digit strings. Numbers are not always integers anyway. You'll lose any leading zeros, for one thing.

Aside: don't use %i for scanf unless the user understands they can enter in other number bases than decimal. If the card number begins with a 0 it will be scanned as octal. Use %d for decimal integers.

Another aside: check the return value from scanf. card is uninitialized going into the loop. If scanf fails to successfully read an int and card happens to be greater than or equal to 1000000000000000 then the erroneous input is left in the buffer ad the program enters an infinite loop.

The variable x is completely pointless and only adds complexity. This is highlighted by the fact that it introduced a bug because you initialized it with the wrong value. You already have a variable i that visits every element in the array, so use that instead and get rid of x entirely.

The answer is in the first comment and others.
I'll try and lay it out in detail.
You initialise x to 1 (int x=1;).
You then have the loop for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) but you actually assign to the array with arr[x] = d; and increment x (x++;).
I think you may have meant arr[i] = d; because i will correctly range from 0 thru 7 (inclusive) but (I hope this is obvious) x is ranging from 1 thru 8 (inclusive) as a redundant parallel loop index.
Arrays in C are subscripted from 0. The valid range for your array is 0 thru 7 (inclusive) because you declared the size to be 8.
Remove x entirely and go with i and you'll have a better time.
'Stack Smashing' is your runtime's slightly obscure way of telling you that you've tried to assign a value outside the range of that array.
In some environments the application would crash and others might (sometimes) work and other times just crash. C is not a forgiving language in general
